# Android (Processing3) Java: "Lost connection while installing device"

Tags: java, android, processing

I'm using processing 3, and I have been having trouble getting AndroidMode to work. I was asking questions, on their official forums, but they got to the point they just said "Google it". 
I keep getting:

> "Lost connection while installing device" and:
>   -post-build:
>
> debug: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_DEXOPT] Shutting down any existing adb
>   server...

Sometimes the error output is different, but it always loses connection.

(And I've tried it with the examples, and anything no matter what code you type it fails)

Comment: The amount of useful feedback people with this problem get is dysmal. i'm currently downloading Android Studio because i keep running into the exact same problem.